# Is there a way to prevent the keyboard from dismissing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I realize that this is the inverse of most posts, but I would like for the keyboard to remain up **even if the 'keyboard down' button is pressed**.

Specifically, I have a view with two `UITextField`s. With the following delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;
}
```

I am able to keep the keyboard up even if the user presses the `Done` button on the keyboard or taps anywhere else on the screen EXCEPT for that pesky keyboard down button on the bottom right of the keyboard.

I am using this view like a modal view (though the view is associated with a ViewController that gets pushed in a UINavigationController), so it really works best from a user perspective to keep the keyboard up all of the time. If anyone knows how to achieve this, please let me know! Thanks!

**UPDATE** Still no solution! When `Done` is pressed, it triggers `textFieldShouldReturn`, but when the `Dismiss` button is pressed, it triggers `textFieldDidEndEditing`. I cannot block the `textField` from ending editing or it **never** goes away. Somehow, I really want to have a method that detects the `Dismiss` button and ignores it. If you know a way, please enlighten me!

Comment: This one of those situations in which you are designing a UI interaction that does not complain with Apple official guidelines. I think you should invest time in rethinking the app instead of "breaking" the rules of the base iOS SDK.

Comment: Which guideline suggests that keeping a keyboard onscreen with textfields is poor UI?

Comment: It's poor UI Interaction not giving the possibility to the user to remove the keyboard, as happens in all the iOS apps. You are trying to do something "strange" if you look at the default look and feel of iOS apps. I cannot remember a single (valid) app that did not give me the possibility of removing the keyboard. This is what I am asking you to think about.

Comment: Ok. Thought about it. Since there is nothing obstructed under the keyboard and the entire modal view is for the sole purpose of entering information in the textfield, in this particular case, I see no issue with disabling the dismiss keyboard button.

Comment: But think about this: what the added value for the user to force such an "iOS-innatural" behaviour for the keyboard? By the way, if you have lots of text fields to write into, if you start editing one and then tap on a different one, you can edit the second one while the keyboard remains on-screen. This is just sufficient, in my opinion.

Comment: I respect your opinion on the matter, but respectfully disagree. I believe dismissing the keyboard will be done in error only and the user may then be at a loss for how to interact with the screen in this particular case. I see the keyboard as akin to a picker in this case, but I do appreciate your point of view.

Comment: I should add that I'm basing my assessment on test-users' feedback, which I believe trumps hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: In defense of PengOne, the iA Writer app keeps the keyboard visible when you are in "fullscreen" mode, even when you tap the "dismiss" button, so there's a use case for this.

Comment: @PengOne  Facing same issue..have you got the best solution for this?Happy to hear from you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***There IS a way to do this.*** Because `UIKeyboard` subclasses `UIWindow`, the only thing big enough to get in `UIKeyboard`'s way is another `UIWindow`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(coverKey) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)coverKey {
    CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIWindow *myWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(r.size.width - 50 , r.size.height - 50, 50, 50)];
    [myWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [super.view addSubview:myWindow];
    [myWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

This works on iPhone apps. Haven't tried it with iPad. You may need to adjust the size of `myWindow`. Also, I didn't do any mem management on `myWindow`. So, consider doing that, too.

Comment: I should have added that I was assuming an instance field approach where previousTextField and someTextField are instance fields. Thus, parameters are not needed for the keyboardWillHide method.

Comment: Even though this covers the "hide keyboard" button, you should still take care of the first responder logic with UITextField delegate methods so that the appropriate UITextField is receiving input from the UIKeyboard.

Comment: My problem with this idea is that it depends on the specific layout/language of the keyboard. I'm not opposed to hacks in general, but this one has to be customized for each keyboard as well as for the different orientations.

Comment: You might be able to just a create a utility class that fires class methods based on orientation changes, focus changes among UITextFields, etc. The class methods would take care of adding/removing/modifying the UIWindows needed to cover specific regions of the keyboard. It is hackish, but it may be the only way.

Comment: +1 A hack, but an effective one. Still holding out for an optimal solution.

Comment: Since the bounty expires soon, I'm awarding it before I forget. This solution is not without its problems, and I would still prefer a better one (hence I am not accepting this answer), but of the suggested answers, this is the only one that achieves the desired result. It definitely deserves my bounty. Thanks JacobB.

Answer (score 8):

I think I've found a good solution.

Add a BOOL as instance variable, let's call it `shouldBeginCalledBeforeHand`

Then implement the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    shouldBeginCalledBeforeHand = YES;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return shouldBeginCalledBeforeHand;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    shouldBeginCalledBeforeHand = NO;
}
```

As well as

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO;
}
```

to prevent the keyboard from disappearing with the return button. The trick is, a focus switch from one textfield to another will trigger a textFieldShouldBeginEditing beforehand. If the dismiss keyboard button is pressed this doesn't happen. The flag is reset after a textfield has gotten focus.

Comment: @PengOne found another solution.

Comment: This works great for just the modal view, but it prevents the keyboard from dismissing at all, even once the view is gone :-(

Comment: Any chance you want to split this into two answers? I like the old solution better because, while imperfect, it doesn't break anything else. Since the solutions are so different, it makes sense to separate them, I think.

Comment: @PengOne divided the answers, can you add some code to show me how you dismsiss the modal view? I think the issue about the not disappearing keyboard can be solved.

Comment: Actually, it's only like a modal view... I have a viewController that gets pushed onto a navController stack, and popped off by the back button on the navBar. Thanks for your help on this one... definitely the best solutions so far...

Comment: @PengOne so you don't show the viewController with `presentModalViewController`?

Comment: Nope. It's nested inside a navController and I don't want to force the user to deal with the screen before going back. I do have a viewWillDisappear method that I can use, and I tried dismissing the keyboard from there, but no luck.

Comment: @PengOne can you call `[self endEditing:yes];` in your viewWillDisappear? Let's see if the keyboard will disappear.

Comment: Not perfect yet, but getting there. I may be able to make this approach work with the right calls at the right time. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This helped me prevent the keyboard going away when using a page view controller.

Answer (score 3):

### Old not perfect solution

I can only think of a not perfect solution. Listen for the notification `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` and make of the textfields first responder again. This will move the keyboard out of sight and back again. You could keep record of which textfield was the last firstResponder by listening for UIKeyboardWillHideNotification and put focus on it in the didHide.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

...

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(id)sender
{
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: +1 since it's a near-solution. The fact that the keyboard goes down and then back up keeps this from being great. I really wish there were a `-(BOOL)keyboardWillHide` method from which I could return `NO`.

Comment: There is a UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, see [UIWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) doc, use that one instead should let you set another text field as first responder, which ought to cancel the keyboard hide/show animation (but I'm not certain).

Comment: @progrmr tried that, didn't work. Maybe you've got a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 9/10 and Swift 3, use this to create a rect which overlaps the "Hide keyboard" - Button

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(coverKey), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}

func coverKey() {
    if let keyboardWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last {
        let r = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let myWindow = UIWindow.init(frame: CGRect(x: r.size.width - 50 , y: r.size.height - 50, width: 50, height: 50))
        myWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        myWindow.isHidden = false
        keyboardWindow.addSubview(myWindow)
        keyboardWindow.bringSubview(toFront: myWindow)
    }
}
```

Notice that this adds a sub view to the keyboard window instead of the main window

Comment: Working well, Need to remove this view while keyboard hiding?

Comment: Since its added to the keyboard window, it should be automatically removed  if you hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a custom on top of the keyboard dismiss button so that the user won't be able to tab the dismiss button. I have used this method in one of my application.

```
- (void)addButtonToKeyboard {

    // create custom button
    UIButton *blockButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    blockButton.frame = //set the frame here, I don't remember the exact frame
    [blockButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"block_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow *appWindows = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView *keyboard;
    for (int i=0; i<[appWindows.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [appWindows.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES && [self.textField isFirstResponder]) {
            [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is JabocB's solution. A hack, and too keyboard specific.

Answer (score -3):

Try this...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   return NO;
}
```

You can use notification as mentioned by Nick Weaver.

Comment: As mentioned in several places, there are **multiple textfields**, so implementing this will not allow the user to move between textfield.