# Keyboard blinks when moving to Next Responder

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented basic Next button on the Text Field using the following code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let didResign = textField.resignFirstResponder()
    if(!didResign) {
        return false
    }

    let myView = getParentView(textField)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { myView.nextField?.contentTextField.becomeFirstResponder() })

    return true
}
```

What annoys me is that before `nextField` becomes First Responder, the keyboard disappears for a brief moment which looks ugly.

The effect is not always visible, sometimes it looks like the keyboard stayed up, sometimes it blinks fast.

Is there a way to resign first responder but still keep the keyboard up?
Move to next field whilst keeping the keyboard?

Comment: you have to put condition , that if it was last textField than resignFirstResponder else make next textField FirstResponder

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006017/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-keyboard-from-dismissing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with UI, you should be on the main queue, so there's no need to dispatch_async to the main queue. Removing this code will make your code cleaner.
The method you're implemented determines the behavior of the app when the return key is pressed. Resigning first responder dismisses the keyboard, so if this is not the effect you want, don't resign first responder.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new at this and I saw this method on the net thinking that first responder thing is separated from keyboard behavior.