# Do not dismiss keyboard on show-segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

We do have an input bar at the bottom of the screen and want to keep the keyboard up when switching the `UIViewController`. The keyboard get dismissed automatically and i couldn't find anything to prevent from this.

How do we prevent the keyboard from being dismissed when we change the `UIViewController` with a `UIStoryboardSegue`?

Comment: On your second controller's viewDidLoad try calling beomeFirstResponder() on your textfield or textview.

Comment: You tried my answer?

Answer (score -1):

There is a property called disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal that you need to set to false to prevent this from happening.

Comment: If i do set this to false on the starting VC it still does dismiss it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to keep a keyboard on:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(coverKey) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)coverKey {
    CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIWindow *myWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(r.size.width - 50 , r.size.height - 50, 50, 50)];
    [myWindow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [super.view addSubview:myWindow];
    [myWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Yes i did but it does not perform in the scenario and it is copy past answer from a different question I have actually read and tried. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006017/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-keyboard-from-dismissing/6040273

Comment: But why did you minus my answer?